# Why is the "move" keyword necessary when it comes to threads; why would I ever not want that behavior?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust, move-semantics

For example (taken from [the Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-01-threads.html#using-move-closures-with-threads)):

```rust
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    println!("Here's a vector: {:?}", v);
});
```

This is not a question about *what* `move` does, but about *why it is necessary to specify*.

*In cases where you want the closure to take ownership of an outside value*, would there ever be a reason not to use the `move` keyword? If `move` is *always* required in these cases, is there any reason why the presence of `move` couldn't just be implied/omitted? For example:

```rust
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let handle = thread::spawn(/* move is implied here */ || {
    // Compiler recognizes that `v` exists outside of this closure's
    // scope and does black magic to make sure the closure takes
    // ownership of `v`.
    println!("Here's a vector: {:?}", v);
});
```

The above example gives the following compile error:

```
closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `v`, which is owned by the current function
```

When the error magically goes away simply by adding `move`, I can't help but wonder to myself: why would I ever *not* want that behavior?

---

I'm not suggesting anything is wrong with the required syntax. I'm just trying to gain a deeper understanding of `move` from people who understand Rust better than I do. :)

Comment: "*In cases where you want the closure to take ownership of an outside value,* would there ever be a reason not to use the move keyword?" - No. That's why `move` exists: to tell the compiler "I want this closure to take ownership of the things it captures."

Comment: Note that you may want to reuse `v` after declaring the closure, and the compiler can't know that. So the `move` is also here to tell the compiler: "_I don't intend to use `v` after this._"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's all about lifetime annotations, and a design decision Rust made long ago.

See, the reason why your `thread::spawn` example fails to compile is because it expects a `'static` closure. Since the new thread can run longer than the code that spawned it, we have to make sure that any captured data stays alive after the caller returns. The solution, as you pointed out, is to pass ownership of the data with `move`.

But the `'static` constraint is a *lifetime annotation*, and a fundamental principle of Rust is that **lifetime annotations never affect run-time behavior**. In other words, lifetime annotations are only there to convince the compiler that the code is correct; they can't change what the code *does*.

If Rust inferred the `move` keyword based on whether the callee expects `'static`, then changing the lifetimes in `thread::spawn` may change when the captured data is dropped. This means that a lifetime annotation is affecting runtime behavior, which is against this fundamental principle. We can't break this rule, so the `move` keyword stays.

---

## Addendum: Why are lifetime annotations erased?

- To give us the freedom to change how lifetime inference works, which allows for improvements like [non-lexical lifetimes (NLL)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html).
- So that alternative Rust implementations like [mrustc](https://github.com/thepowersgang/mrustc) can save effort by ignoring lifetimes.
- Much of the compiler assumes that lifetimes work this way, so to make it otherwise would take a huge effort with dubious gain. (See [this article by Aaron Turon](https://aturon.github.io/blog/2017/07/08/lifetime-dispatch/); it's about specialization, not closures, but its points apply just as well.)

Answer (score 11):

There are actually a few things in play here. To help answer your question, we must first understand why `move` exists.

Rust has 3 types of closures:

1. [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), a closure that *consumes* its captured variables (and hence can only be called once),
2. [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), a closure that *mutably borrows* its captured variables, and
3. [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), a closure that *immutably borrows* its captured variables.

When you create a closure, Rust infers which trait to use based on how the closure uses the values from the environment. The manner in which a closure captures its environment depends on its type. A `FnOnce` captures by value (which may be a move or a copy if the type is `Copy`able), a `FnMut` mutably borrows, and a `Fn` immutably borrows. *However*, if you use the `move` keyword when declaring a closure, it will **always** "capture by value", or take ownership of the environment before capturing it. Thus, the `move` keyword is irrelevant for `FnOnce`s, but it changes how `Fn`s and `FnMut`s capture data.

Coming to your example, Rust infers the type of the closure to be a `Fn`, because `println!` only requires a reference to the value(s) it is printing (the Rust book page you linked talks about this when explaining the error without `move`). The closure thus attempts to borrow `v`, and the standard lifetime rules apply. Since `thread::spawn` requires that the closure passed to it have a `'static` lifetime, the captured environment must also have a `'static` lifetime, which `v` does not outlive, causing the error. You must thus explicitly specify that you want the closure to take ownership of `v`.

This can be further exemplified by changing the closure to something that the compiler would infer to be a `FnOnce` -- `|| v`, as a simple example. Since the compiler infers that the closure is a `FnOnce`, it captures `v` by value by default, and the line `let handle = thread::spawn(|| v);` compiles without requiring the `move`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct. The `move` keyword and `Fn` traits are orthogonal. And `Vec<T>` is *never* `Copy`.

Comment: @LambdaFairy apologies, I mistakenly assumed that `Vec<T: Copy>` is `Copy`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @EvilTak A good rule of thumb is to remember that, unlike C++'s copy ctors, which may contain arbitrary code, Rust implements copy as a straight bitwise copy of the memory occupied by the value itself (or behaves _as if_ it were implemented that way). Since a `Vec` consists of three machine words one of which is a pointer to heap-allocated data, making `Vrc` copy would cause two `Vec`s to point to the same data, wreaking havoc at `Drop` time and causing aliasing issues before that.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers have great information, which led me to an understanding that is easier for me to think about, and hopefully easier for other Rust newcomers to get.

---

Consider this simple Rust program:

```rust
fn print_vec (v: &Vec<u32>) {
    println!("Here's a vector: {:?}", v);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    print_vec(&v); // `print_vec()` borrows `v`
    v.push(4);
}
```

Now, asking why the `move` keyword can't be implied is like asking why the "&" in `print_vec(&v)` can't also be implied.

[Rust’s central feature is *ownership*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#what-is-ownership). You can't just tell the compiler, "Hey, here's a bunch of code I wrote, now please discern perfectly everywhere I intend to reference, borrow, copy, move, etc. Kthnxsbye!" Symbols and keywords like `&` and `move` are a necessary and integral part of the language.

In hindsight, this seems really obvious, and makes my question seem a little silly!